# Как принять json массив в сервлете?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, java-ee, сервлеты

Здравствуйте, через аякс посылаю json массив сервлету , на сервлете не могу его правильно принять , помогите пожалуйста с этой проблемой. Вот мой аякс :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: ko.toJSON(self.ViewMass()),
    content: "UTF-8",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "http://localhost:8080/MyDiplomka/ServResult",
    success: function (responseText) {
        var a = responseText;
        alert(a);
    }
});
```

в аяксе всё в порядке , через firebag видно что посылается на сервлет массив вот такого типа :

```js
[
 {"QContent":"3+5",
  "Answers":[
            {"AContent":"8","RAnswer":false},
            {"AContent":"22","RAnswer":false},
            {"AContent":"33","RAnswer":false}
            ]
 }
]
```

В сервлете пытаюсь получить данный массив , только не очень получается(пытаюсь распарсить с помощью json-simple), подскажите как можно получить такой массив, сейчас просто считываю в строку и вывожу , вот собственно сервлет :

```
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
        String wq = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(wq);
```

Comment: в строку я то могу получить , но эту строку можно вывести только в System.out.println(wq); - ну а вытащить из неё значение какое либо не представляется возможным